# Transpose in gradient layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

Why is tranposes visible in a gradient in Photoshop?

How can you get rid of the transposes.. Does it have something to do with the color depth? The optimized PNG is in 24 bit

Look in the dark grey area to the left

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this gradient is going through grey shades that are very close together (only about 15 bits different), there are few 'steps', so to speak, that can be distributed from one side of the gradient to the other. (A 24-bit PNG has 255 "steps" between white and black.) The way to solve this is with dithering, which distributes the "steps" in a random blend pattern instead of lining them up in a clearly-visible horizontal line. **In Photoshop CS6 and higher, there's a `dithering` checkbox in the gradient tool**, which should get rid of the transposes.

Disclaimer: I'm not a Photoshop or graphic expert, this is just my explanation of how color depth works.  http://bjango.com/articles/gradients/ is a great article on gradients that discusses dithering about halfway down the page.